# Check if list entry contains word sequence java

Tags: java, string, list

I would like to only add Strings to the list if the list not already contains an entry that contains the exact same character sequence.

**This does not work... "String" will be added**

```
list1.add("String");
list2.add("Hello I am String");

for (String str : list1) {
        if (!list2.contains(str))
            list2.add(str);
    }
```

The word "String" will be added even though an entry of list2 contains "String". How can I tell it to not only check of identical character sequences? Do I have to get through every single entry manually with forloops or RegEx? Or is there a nicer way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through both lists in loops:

```
outer: for (String str1 : list1) {
    for (String str2: list2) {
        if (str2.contains(str1)) {
            continue outer;
        }
    }

    list2.add(str);
}
```

This will check every element of `list2` for the substring.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use String.contains and not the contains of the collection (which matches the entire String).
Therefore you'll have to iterate over all the Strings in the list and run String.contains on each one.

```
for (String str : list1) {
   boolean found = false;
   for (String str2 : list2) {
        if (str2.contains(str)) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
   }
   if (!found) {
       list2.add(str);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong..

```
list1.add("String");
list2.add("Hello I am String");

for (String str : list1) {
        if (!list2.contains(str)) 
       //The above line checks if list2 contains "String". It doesn't check if list2's Strings contain "String".
       // so, iterate over each value of list2 and check for string.contains(). 
            list2.add(str);
    }
```